# Help me with the proof the limit(rigorous proof)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the limit and prove it

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}|1-2+3-4+...+(-1)^{n-1}n|$$
It's obvious to find that the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.
$\\$
I tried use squeze theorem. But still can't work out.please give me some hints...

Comment: Hint: Compute the exact value of the alternated sum in $|\ |$ when $n=2k$ and when $n=2k+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this sequence is not convergent, As the hint points out, we can inductively prove this:

\begin{equation}
s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n i(-1)^i=
\begin{cases}
-k & \text{if $n=2k$}\\
k+1 & \text{if $n=2k+1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Indeed, for $n=1$, we have $s_1=1=0\cdot 1+1$, for $n=2=2\cdot 1$ we have $s_2=-1$. Now, assume we have 
\begin{equation}
s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n i(-1)^i=
\begin{cases}
-k & \text{if $n=2k$}\\
k+1 & \text{if $n=2k+1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for a certain $n$. If $n=2k$ then $s_n=-k$, which implies that for $n+1$, $s_{n+1}=s_n-(n+1)(-1)^{(n+1)}=-k+2k+1=k+1$. If $n=2k+1$ then $s_n=k+1$, which implies that for $n+1$, $s_{n+1}=s_n-(n+1)(-1)^{(n+1)}=k+1-2k+2=-(k+1)$

With this, we note
\begin{equation}
\frac{s_n}{n}=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2} & \text{if $n=2k$}\\
\frac{k+1}{2k+1} & \text{if $n=2k+1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then, the subsequence $s_{2k}$ converges to $-0.5$, while the subsequence $s_{2k+1}$ converges to $0.5$.

As this sequence has two subsequences which converge to different limits, it is not convergent.

Comment: But with "| |" the sequence is convergent right?

Comment: BTW thanks for sharing the idea

Comment: @Chiu-Tzu-Hsuan Indeed. I thought "| |" meant parenthesis "()", not the norm. Sorry.

Comment: hahaha ლ(・ω・ლ) .